# Manually subscribe and call updateFromJS causes dead-lock

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some code below to make sure that a user does not need to click any button and update all input to server side. Server side code is responsible to perform any calculation and send updated JSON back to client.

The issue here is that manual subscription code will detect the user input change, it will call to a function to post JSON data to server and receive JSON from server. From this point it will try to update the view model by calling `ko.mapping.updateFromJS(viewModel, data);`, but a dead-lock happens here. The `updateFromJS` will trigger the manual subscription event again, thus server code is called again, which triggers another round of manual subscription.

```
var initialData = /* get JSON from server side */;

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);

viewModel.Product.Parameter1.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    postToServer();
});

viewModel.Product.Parameter2.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    postToServer();
});

viewModel.Product.Parameter3.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    postToServer();
});

function getProduct() {
    // retrieve JSON data to be posted to server side
}

function postToServer() {
    var product = getProduct();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ProductUpdate/',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // update JSON returned from server side to observable view-model
            ko.mapping.updateFromJS(viewModel, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to do either of following:

- Disable manual subscribe while `ko.mapping.updateFromJS` is called? (Resuming afterwards).
- Have manual subscription ignore the event triggered by a `ko.mapping.updateFromJS` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do it with a variable like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var initialData = /* get JSON from server side */;

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

var preventUpdate = false;

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);

viewModel.Product.Parameter1.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (!preventUpdate) postToServer();
});
```

and then in the `postToServer` function

```
success: function (data) {
    // update JSON returned from server side to observable view-model

    preventUpdate = true;
    ko.mapping.updateFromJS(data, viewModel);
    preventUpdate = false;
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, my current approach is to disable subscription first and re-eable later on.